# Is it Good Practice to Change Apache's /var/www/ (Default Root Directory)?

Tags: permissions, apache2, php

When you install Apache, PHP's default folder is /var/www/ by default. Some developers find it necessary to change the root directory to something like:

/home/public_html/ (many shared hosting environments use this)
/home/user/

Of course, this requires some tweaking and if you're in the development phase perhaps it's less of a hassle to stick with /var/www/.

What do you think? Should you change the root directory? What are the pros and cons?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I believe you should. We started doing that to understand Apache and it settings but it is now a sort of standard agreement we have when installing a new site for a client.

- Backup wise it is easier. We host about 100 sites and have our software in /u1/ and then directories to programs and data and also a www directory where the webserver software is. So a backup/restore of /u1/"client_name"/ is easy and there is nothing outside the directory for that instance. Besides that: the MySQL databases are stored in those individual directories too.
- It is always better to change the default since security wise you make it a bit more difficult to guess. We also always change the www-data user and group to a more specific one.

Comment: Is it alright to temporarily use the /var/www/ folder, then when you are finished development move it to a more secure location like /home/public_html/ ? Or, would you advise for starting off with a different root to begin with?

Comment: I  would start from the beginning.

Comment: What potential hassles/ issues may I encounter otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I think it's entirely up to you.

Going with the default might give you less headaches down the road. Scenarios where changing it could be a bad thing:

- Emergency maintenance (by an outside contractor/sys admin/whoever) might be hampered by a non-default configuration.
- Default backup configurations for web servers might have to be modified as well.

But then again, you can also gain a little bit more security (through obscurity) and organization, maybe by choosing a better naming convention (/site1, /site2, etc).

That being said, I don't think that it matters that much. You could always change the `/var/www` directory to be a symbolic link (to point wherever you want) anyways, without even modifying the configuration to begin with.